# Nolio deployment - Deploy multiple artifacts from Bamboo build to different servers

Tags: deployment, bamboo, nolio

I have a single .Net solution which has got UI project and WCF service project.
I donot want to maintain 2 solutions and deploy UI and Service separately. 
I succeeded in building the solution and creating the UI artifact package and Services artifact package from the respective Bamboo tasks (zipping the respective project o/p from MSBuild output).
Now I have 2 artifacts to be deployed to 2 servers.
UI should go to UI servers and Service should go to Service servers.
Can this be done at the Bamboo deployment project level or at the Nolio configuration level?
I know I can do 2 Babmoo build plans (building the UI and Service source codes) and 2 deployments for UI and Service, but I am trying whether I can optimize it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe correct way to handle this is to assign the UI artifact to the UI Server Type, and assign the Service artifact to the Service Server Type.....then create a package that contains both artifacts, and they will automatically be distributed to the correct server(s).  I assume you are using CARA (formerly Nolio) 6.x?

Comment: We are using CA Release automation tool that uses Nolio for deployments. I found a way to pick and choose artifacts that come out of a Bamboo build.

Comment: I found a way to pick and choose artifacts for a deployment environment. On a Bamboo deployment project, add a task for deployment environment and add an Atrifact task on it as here:https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tasks-for-deployment-environments-339051206.html . Here note that you can add more than one artifacts to the deployment environment. Thank you.. Your answer helped me to dig in to this possibility.!

Comment: Glad i could help, Sudheer, yes, we are constantly improving integrations with CI tools such as Bamboo.  Never hesitate to ask!